# Hide normal failure output from phpunit assert

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

By default, when an assert fails in PHPUnit it will print out an error along with the values of the variables in the assert. This is generally a usefull behavior, but in my case it prints out a large block of useless data (I'm asserting that an object has been destroyed) that clutters my error output.

I tried passing an error message for the optional 2nd parameter, but all this does is output my error above the standard PHPUnit output. Is there a method to actually hide the standard error output?

Here is my current assert:
`$this->assertFalse($json, 'JSON not removed');`

Comment: So your problem is that the object is being dumped? Can you show the actual assert sentence?

Comment: @gontrollez its a JSON object that im asserting has been removed from storage. Code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is generally bad practice (precisely because it would hide the actual values), in this case you can do the comparison yourself:

```
$this->assertTrue(false === $json, 'JSON not removed');
```

Another way is with assertEmpty. It won't dump the array and will pass if $json is false:

```
$this->assertEmpty($json, 'JSON not removed');
```